# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

**i have Tried the following code and shows me the error!**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command

def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who the heck is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who the heck is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    elif 'date' in command:
        talk('sorry, I have a headache')
    elif 'are you single' in command:
        talk('I am in a relationship with wifi')
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_alexa()
```

**But it Shows me error in the following pattern!**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/touhid/PycharmProjects/untitled1/dictionary.py", line 60, in 
run_alexa()
File "/home/touhid/PycharmProjects/untitled1/dictionary.py", line 35, in run_alexa
command = take_command()
File "/home/touhid/PycharmProjects/untitled1/dictionary.py", line 31, in take_command
return command
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception in your try-except block. Most likely in following lines

```
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
```

If you define `command=''` before the try block you won't get the error. But the program won't work anyway till you solve why the exception is coming.

Change to following:

```
def take_command():
    try:
        command = ''
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Comment: The problem still remains. If you get any error in the lines I pasted in my answer, the variable command never come into existence. Since you just `pass` when exception comes, you go directly to `return command` and your program has no idea what 'command' is.

Answer (score 1):

in take_command() the Exception can be raised before line
`command = listener.recognize_google(voice)`
So that`s why it can be undefined.

Fix it  like this:

```
def take_command():
    command = None  # (<-- !!!)
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Answer (score 0):

A missing depending package could cause this error. To fix it, try:

> `pip install pyaudio`

If this doesn't work, temporarily comment the `try` and `except` code parts in `take_command`, and run the code. This might give an error in one of the dependency packages such as `speech_recognition`.

Check which import(module name) is not defined, and install it with `pip`.

Note that I'm using python 3.6 on Windows.